Курсор в ipython для vscode
В очередной раз запускаю скрипт в консоли ipython для vscode. После запуска курсор непонятно где. Как сделать что бы курсор стоял на вводе в консоли? На стандартной консоли vscode там где надо. И да поставить вручную тоже могу. Как сделать что бы он сам туда перескочил после запуска?
